# Retrieving list of Distribution Groups

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to retrieve a list of Distribution groups with their x400 and x500 addresses.  I have determined the attributes are proxyaddresses and TextEncodedORAddress.  We are running Exchange 2013.  When I look at a high level searchbase like "OU=Exchange,OU=company,DC=company,DC=com" and use Get-ADUser it returns the user accounts, however I need Distribution Groups.
Using the following returns the users with the attributes I need, but I need distribution groups, not users.

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Exchange,OU=company,DC=company,DC=com" `
-Filter * -Properties * | Select * |
FT CN,distinguishedName,proxyaddresses,textEncodedORAddress
```

I tried Get-Mailbox, Get-DistributionGroup, but I get an error saying it's not a cmdlet.  I also tried using the attribute groupType to filter, but it didn't work.  I'm not sure if I'm able to use Get-ADObject as I'm not quite sure how I'd use that cmdlet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Get-ADGroup? you tried that?

Comment: That seems to have done it.  I guess because this is an exchange group for distribution lists, I wasn't thinking about it as an AD group, like a security group.  Thank you for pointing that out .  I should have known better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are multiple values in that proxyaddresses, I was receiving Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection, therefore I had to use the following.

```
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Exchange,OU=Company,DC=company,DC=com" `
-Filter * -Properties proxyAddresses | Select CN,distinguishedName,textEncodedORAddress,`
@{L=’ProxyAddress_1′; E={$_.proxyaddresses[0]}},
@{L=’ProxyAddress_2′; E={$_.ProxyAddresses[1]}},
@{L=’ProxyAddress_3′; E={$_.proxyaddresses[2]}},
@{L=’ProxyAddress_4′; E={$_.proxyaddresses[3]}},
@{L=’ProxyAddress_5′; E={$_.proxyaddresses[4]}}|
Export-CSV C:\temp\x500_Export.csv
```

The only thing I can't figure out for the output, is why I see the various proxyaddresses and the distinguishedname, however it won't show CN, or displayname.  Those are blank.

Comment: -properties cn,proxyaddresses,displayname?

Comment: Yeah, my select statement as I understand it, should output CN, distinguishedName, textEdcodedORAddress, and then the array of proxyaddresses.  But the only output is distinguishedname, and array of proxyaddresses.  The CN, textencodedORaddress is blank.  If I also add in displayname, it's blank also.

Comment: what i meant - try adding ``-properties cn,proxyaddresses,displayname``explicitly?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  That totally worked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I was looking for some way to upvote your comment, however I don't see any arrows near it, and searching for why, I see that I need a rep of 15?? to upvote.  As I only have 8 :( I can't yet.  Or is there another way?

Comment: i don't know ;) not that big of an expert in all these rating based things ;). well, maybe when you get there, if you have time ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
get-adgroup -filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution'"
```